# how to get tr between two positions

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I have this HTML:

```
<table>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
</table>
```

I want to get the `tr` third to before the last.

### What I have tried:

I can get from the third to the last like this:
`tr[position()>2]`

**but i don't want the last `tr`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following to exclude the final `tr`:

```
tr[position() > 2 and position() < last()]
```

Comment: Yes it works, i will accept your answer, please is there any way to except the 7th tr please?

Comment: I'm confused. Which elements do you want to select exactly?

Comment: the elements between 3 and 46 except the 7th tr

Comment: You can use any combination of checks in the predicate. For example: `tr[position() > 2 and position() != 7 and position() < 47]`